# Pandas DataFrame column difference of max and min value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the difference of max and min vale of a column.

```
range = DiabeticPatients.diff(DiabeticPatients['Glucose'].max() - 
                              DiabeticPatients['Glucose'].min())
```

also, want to use lambda to correct it.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.ptp()` (peak-to-peak) to get the max-minus-min:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [3]: np.random.seed(444)                                                     

In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Glucose": np.random.randint(0, 10000, size=100)}) 

In [5]: df['Glucose'].ptp()                                                                                                                                   
Out[5]: 9947
```

Comment: Pandas `ptp` is [deprecated since 0.24.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.ptp.html) (which leads to `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'ptp'`).  The solution now is to use `np.ptp(df['Glucose'])`.